# How to auto-fill cells down for target cells moving horizontal?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc I would like to auto-fill cells down (menu: sheet -> fill cells -> down) but the referenced target cell move right.

Example:
[image]

What do I have to type in cell A3 in order to auto-fill cells A4 and A5 by selecting auto-fill down?

Seems an easy task, but unfortunately I could not find a solution with Google. Perhaps I am missing the right keyword to search for.

Comment: Old question that was just bumped.  You could do the references with a formula using OFFSET or INDEX.  But a simple solution is just to copy A1:C1, then in A3, paste-special, transpose.

Comment: `OFFSET` or `INDEX` are usually used with `ROW` OR `COLUMN`. So, for cell `A3`, that would be `=OFFSET($A$1, 0, ROW(A3) - 3)`, which can then be filled down. Regarding the alternative, “Paste Special” with the “Transpose” option, if you want the same result, it seems you have to choose “Values”, not “Formulas” – so you cannot preserve formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I don' know if I understand question correctly but hope my answer will be useful.
You could add alphabetic sequence to `Sort Lists` setting and it will fill cells with letters likewise numbers in incremental way.

How to do it:
1. Go to `Tools > Options > LibreOffice Calc > Sort Lists`
2. Click `New` button
3. Enter uppercase alphabetic sequence one character by line
4. Click `Add` button
5. Repeat with lowercase sequence if you need

Now if you enter any letter in cell and pull right-bottom corner the cells will be filled with alphabetically incremented letters.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fill down, select cells `A3:A5` and then choose the fill down command you mentioned. Note that in your example, this will overwrite the contents of cells `A4:A5`. The result looks like:

[image: Results after fill down operation]

If you want to fill right, select cells `A3:C3` and then choose the fill right command (menu: **Sheet** → **Fill Cells** → **Right**). This results in:

[image: Results after fill right operation]

Or did you mean something different?

Comment: The question was not about how the GUI and the menu options work, but how you can fill *down* formulas that reference cells going *right*.